# junit testing service with injected repository

Tags: java, spring, junit

i have a service i need to test, it has injected repository

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    private MyRepo myRepo;

    public someFunctionToTest(){
        // body...
    }
}
```

however i can not figure out how to write a proper junit tests for service

i have tryed following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Application.class })
@Configuration
public class NumberGeneratorServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @Inject
    private MyRepository MyRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //do something
    }

}
```

in this case im getting error: `Failed to load ApplicationContext`
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getMyRepository': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?`

what is the proper way to test Services with injections?

EDIT: MyRepository

```
@Repository
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository {

    @Inject
    private MyJPARepository entityRepository;

//some methods

}
```

Comment: where is the implementation of MyRepository ?

Comment: added implementation

Comment: what is your class private MyRepo myRepo;

Comment: It seems you have a problem to do the beans injections, it may be because invalid configuration or failure to load configuration file. Can you post your configuration file?